# Javascript: union of multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to write a function that will return a union of the array arguments passed.

I don't want to use a decrementing while statement nor the underscore _.union function.

union([1,4,78,98],[45,56,3],[2,3,45]);

returns --> [1,4,78,98,45,56,2]

This is what I have so far and it is not correct:

```
    union: function(){
      var i, j, k;
      var newArray = [];

      for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        j = arguments[i];
        l = k[arguments[i]];
          for (){
              j = k[i];
              newArray.push(j);
          }
      }
          return newArray;
      }
```

I was hoping I can arrive at a solution with multiple for loops.

Comment: What's the result you get? Why is it not correct?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to flatten then remove duplicates. In a functional style you could do something like this:

```
function union() {
  var arrs = [].concat.apply([], arguments);
  return arrs.filter(function(v, i) {
    return arrs.indexOf(v) == i;
  });
}
```

That should give you the same result as Underscore's `union`.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/azulok/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()`.

```
union([1,4,78,98],[45,56,3],[2,3,45]);

function union() {
    return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(res, arr) {
        return res.concat(arr.filter(function(item) { 
                                         return res.indexOf(item) === -1;
                                     }))
    })
}
```

---

Break it up a little if you prefer:

```
function union() {
    return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(res, arr) {
        return res.concat(arr.filter(notIn(res)))
    })
}

function notIn(arr) {
    return function(item) {
       return arr.indexOf(item) === -1;
    }
}
```

---

And of course you can reuse the `.reduce()` callback as well, so that if you actually have an Array of Arrays, you can do this:

```
var res = arrays.reduce(joinUnique);

function joinUnique(res, arr) {
    return res.concat(arr.filter(notIn(res)))
}

function notIn(arr) {
    return function(item) {
       return arr.indexOf(item) === -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing it is to use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const data = new Set([...[1,4,78,98], ...[45,56,3], ...[2,3,45]]);

data.forEach(i => console.log(i));
```